# Blackberry : how to play *.swf/*.flv file?

Tags: blackberry

I want to play flash file in my BB application.

is it possible ? if yes then pls help me out to implement this in my application

waiting for your suggession...

thanking you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash is not currently supported by BlackBerry devices, however Adobe and RIM have announced upcoming support for Flash 10.1 -- if I had to guess it will be part of OS 6.0.